# Redux data structuring

Tags: javascript, architecture, hierarchical-data, flux, redux

I'm trying to build a complex fully-dynamic app with [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux). I mean my App has lots of dynamic-generated forms with generated fields-components on-the-fly. I want to store in my Redux-store visual data about my components too. But how should i do it without mixing real data with visual component data?

For example if i have structure like this

```
Store { 
  visual: {...deeply nested visual-data-tree...}, 
  data: {...deeply-nested real-data-tree...} 
}
```

It is hard to render component because i need to search visual data first, then react component "value" in two trees.

But if have a structure similar to this:

```
Store {
  form {
    visual: {...form visual data...},
    data: {
      //Ok here the form "data" - widgets. Or it must to be visual? :)
      widget1 {
        visual: {type:"ComboBox", opened: true},
        data: 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You see the problem, now i have visual data inside real data of Form widget.

(form - ***data*** - widget1 - ***visual***)

Visual data inside the real data is out of the concept.

How do you guys solve same problems of mixing data?

Really sorry for my poor english. I hope i clearly explained the problem.

Comment: This is currently being discussed in the Redux community - you can track it's progress/discussion here https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/159.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so i'll track it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Isn't the distinction superficial? I think a more important rule is that the data in the state should be normalized. For example, if you have `Combobox` widget letting you choose users, your data shape better be

```
{
  chosenUserId: 10, // Good!
  users: {
    10: { name: 'Alice' }
}
```

rather than

```
{
  chosenUser: { name: 'Alice' }, // Bad!
  users: {
    10: { name: 'Alice' }
}
```

If the data is duplicated in the state tree, it's hard to update it correctly and avoid inconsistencies.

As long as you keep the data normalized, I see no real need to divide `visual` and `data`. You might want to have top-level entity cache that looks like a database (e.g. `entities` which includes `users`, `posts`, or whatever data objects your app uses), but other than that, go with whatever state shape feels most comfortable when retrieving the relevant state.

Comment: Is there then an easy way how to go back from normalized data to a nested structure when actually rendering the data to DOM?

Comment: I would just write [“selectors”](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) manually and use them from `mapStateToProps` of the components.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I am doing right now. I was wondering if this could be automated somehow. For example by implementing something like `normalizr.denormalize()` which would replace entity IDs by the actual objects (used only right before passing to view for rendering).

Comment: @PetrPeller Try googling it, I think a few people tries to do this and somebody’s fork even implemented something similar